# SQL Access GROUP BY et ID

Tags: sql, ms-access

I found out some examples but I have difficulties applying this to my case and as I need the query very quickly, I am coming to you SQL masters :)

I need the below `SELECT` to return `Sessions.id` (the one that corresponds to Max(Sessions.DateFin) for each row)

```
SELECT Sessions.idFormation,
       Inscriptions.idPersonnel, 
       Max(Sessions.DateFin) AS Dernier 
FROM Sessions 
INNER JOIN Inscriptions ON Sessions.id = Inscriptions.idSession 
GROUP BY Sessions.idFormation, Inscriptions.idPersonnel
```

I believe I need to use something like (this one has nothing to do with my above query, just an example from some internet forum)

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1
JOIN 
(
   SELECT category, MAX(date) AS MAXDATE
   FROM Table1
   GROUP BY category
) t2
ON T1.category = t2.category
AND t1.date = t2.MAXDATE
```

but as t1 in my case is already a query I do not get how to implement this solution.

Comment: What do you mean "T1 is already a query"?

Comment: Thanks for reply. If found out the solution. not sure it is optimal bu it works and do not have much time to spend on it.

Comment: If you have time now, I suggest you click on "Accept" for the most useful answer below (including your own).  That way we all know an Answer can be found here, not only a Question.

Comment: I have done so. I could not accept my own answer at that time due to user limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the query that works. I'm sure it can be simplified but how.

```
SELECT T1.idFormation AS idFormation, T1.idPersonnel AS idPersonnel, T2.Dernier,     T1.Validé AS Validé 
FROM (SELECT Sessions.idFormation, Inscriptions.idPersonnel, Sessions.DateFin,     Sessions.Validé 
    FROM Sessions 
    INNER JOIN Inscriptions ON Sessions.id = Inscriptions.idSession) T1
INNER JOIN 
( SELECT Sessions.idFormation, Inscriptions.idPersonnel, Max(Sessions.DateFin) AS     Dernier FROM Sessions INNER JOIN Inscriptions ON Sessions.id = Inscriptions.idSession GROUP BY     Sessions.idFormation, Inscriptions.idPersonnel
) T2 
ON T1.idFormation = T2.idFormation 
AND T1.idPersonnel = T2.idPersonnel 
AND T1.DateFin = T2.Dernier
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Make that as a `Subselect` and give a `alias name` to that `Subselect` then join with the existing subselect

```
SELECT * FROM (--your query--) t1
JOIN 
(
   SELECT category, MAX(date) AS MAXDATE
   FROM Table1
   GROUP BY category
) t2
ON T1.category = t2.category
AND t1.date = t2.MAXDATE
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT s.id, s.idFormation, i.idPersonnel, si.maxdate AS Dernier 
FROM (Sessions as s INNER JOIN
      Inscriptions as i
      ON s.id = i.idSession) INNER JOIN
     (SELECT category, MAX(s.date) as maxdate
      FROM Sessions as s INNER JOIN
           Inscriptions as i
            ON s.id = i.idSession
      GROUP BY s.idFormation, i.idPersonnel
     ) as si
     ON si.category = ??.category AND
        si.maxdate = s.date;
```

I don't know which table the category comes from; fill that in instead of `??`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. If found out the solution. not sure it is optimal bu it works and do not have much time to spend on it.